# What minimum speed does one need to be able to go over a rail in Trackmania Nations Forever?

Tags: trackmania-forever

In Trackmania Nations Forever, what minimum speed does one need to be able to go over a rail?

By going over a rail, I mean:

It could be done either going forward or backward. In the example above I was going at 108 backward.  The speed would differ  depending on whether the rail is straight or is a curve.

Comment: I'm still interested in the answer.

Comment: If anyone has any idea.